# Is There a way to use the Parameter Names from a typedef

Tags: c++, parameters, arguments, function-pointers, typedef

So given a `typedef` that defines a function pointer with parameter names like this:

```
typedef void(*FOO)(const int arg);
```

Is there a way that I can just use this function pointer to define the signature of my function? Obviously this won't work, but I'd like to somehow use the `typedef` to specify a function signature with a corresponding type:

```
FOO foo {
    cout << arg << endl;
}
```

Again, I know this doesn't work, and is bad syntax. It will just give the error:

> error: `arg` was not declared in this scope

Comment: You can't declare a function like that. Typedefs with functions are for function pointers/references.

Comment: what would you expect `cout << arg << endl;` to print ?

Comment: `FOO` is a function pointer. What is `FOO foo { /* statements */ }` supposed to mean?

Comment: This question doesn't make any sense.  `FOO` is a typedef to a function pointer.  It is not a short way to write `void FOO(const int arg)`

Comment: @Tyker I was trying to use it to define a function. So I would expect it to print whatever was passed into the defined function. For example: I'd hope this could be called like `foo(13)`

Comment: @NathanOliver Obviously this doesn't work, I give the error in the question. I'm going to have a ton of functions who's definitions must match this `typedef` I was wondering if there was a way that I could enforce that.

Comment: Depends on how you use them.  You might be able to use some sort of interface that uses a compile time check to make sure the function has the right signature.  As an aside, how would you have named the different functions if this actually worked?

Comment: @MivVG I understand that... Obviously with the error. I'm just trying to keep the `typedef` and the function signature in sync. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: @NathanOliver I mean, I was hoping for some syntax where I could just do `FOO foo{}`, `FOO bar{}`, and so on. Again I get that this doesn't work. I was just hoping someone could suggest an alternative.

Comment: @Ron perhaps I misunderstand? How would that assist with specifying function signatures?

Comment: @PasserBy I mean that's obviously bad syntax, I'm just trying to give an example of what I want to do. I'd like to be able to use the signature specified in the `typedef` to specify a function signature as I define it.

Answer (score 2):

What you are trying to do will not work.  `FOO` is an alias for `void(*)(const int)`. so

```
FOO foo {
    cout << arg << endl;
}
```

becomes

```
void(*)(const int) foo {
    cout << arg << endl;
}
```

and that just doesn't work.  What you can do though is define a macro that takes a name and use that to stamp out a function signature.  That would look like

```
#define MAKE_FUNCTION(NAME) void NAME(const int arg)

MAKE_FUNCTION(foo){ std::cout << arg * 5 << "\n"; }

MAKE_FUNCTION(bar){ std::cout << arg * 10 << "\n"; }

int main()
{
    foo(1);
    bar(2);
}
```

Comment: Well... Not what I was hoping for but at least it tries to answer the question +1.

Comment: @JonathanMee Thanks.  This is the best I can think of right now for what you are actually trying to accomplish.  If I think of something else I'll add it to the answer and ping you.

Comment: I've tried to clean up the question to make more clear that this is the best answer... But who knows? I seem to have really failed on this question.

Answer (score 1):

The definition of a function pointer has nothing to do with the declaration nor the definition of a function so the answer is no.

Comment: Well, it may have _something_ to do with it - for example, this `FOO f();` is perfectly valid function declaration.

Comment: @NeilButterworth How vexing :)

Comment: On the contrary, obviously a function pointer can only address a function with a matching signature, so there is a direct correlation. I'm trying to find a way to define a function according to the corresponding function signature.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this actually. You can abuse lambdas to clone a function by assigning an auto lambda to the type. The downside is you lose access to the argument names, and have to access the arguments by index instead.

https://github.com/stevemk14ebr/PolyHook_2_0/blob/350f6723f0c12b93085273fc4a5208aaa36bf41a/polyhook2/IHook.hpp#L67-L150

here's an example of the usage
https://github.com/stevemk14ebr/PolyHook_2_0/blob/350f6723f0c12b93085273fc4a5208aaa36bf41a/UnitTests/windows/TestDetourx64.cpp#L22-L41